# VSCode Live Share: run electron app for both participants

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

How do I let the other person run the terminal command

`npm start`

so that it opens up for them and not for myself?

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76497156/11107541 ?